# reactjs - can we access js var in react component which is stored in other file?

Tags: javascript, .net, reactjs, model-view-controller

I have an old project where i have stored all var in .cshtml file in  tag

cshtml code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var foo = 'foo'
</script>
```

now I want to access that var in my new module. it's in react

```
 render() {
 return <div className="vertical-box-column width-280 resizableMenu solutionExplorer">
            //want to access foo here;I can get var using window {window.foo} but not directly {foo}
        </div>
```

}

I am able to get var foo by {window.foo}

is there any way to get var directly, without window keyword

Also Can I get foo in local Environment : localhost:3000 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set your variable in component state and use that state variable in render function. For example:

```
 constructor (props) {
       super(props)

       this.state = {
        test: testVarFromHTML
    }
}
render () {
    return <div>{test}</div>
}
```